# touchesEnded:withEvent: not detecting the top node in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, uiresponder

I have a custom class `Object` derived from `SKSpriteNode` with an `SKLabelNode` member variable.

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface Object : SKSpriteNode {
    SKLabelNode* n;
}

@end
```

In the implementation, I set up the `SKLabelNode`.

```
#import "Object.h"

@implementation Object

- (instancetype) initWithImageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:name];

    n = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Courier"];
    n.text = @"Hello";
    n.zPosition = -1;
    //[self addChild:n];

    return self;
}
```

**Note:** I have not yet added the `SKLabelNode` as a child to `Object`.  I have the line commented out.

I have a separate class derived from `SKScene`.  In this class, I add an instance of `Object` as a child. This is my `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method in this class:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint loc = [touch locationInNode:self];
    NSArray* nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:loc]; //to find all nodes at the touch location
    SKNode* n = [self nodeAtPoint:loc]; //to find the top most node at the touch location

    NSLog(@"TOP: %@",[n class]);
    for(SKNode* node in nodes) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[node class]);
    }
}
```

When I tap on the instance of `Object` in my `SKScene` class, it works as I expected. It detects the node is an instance of `Object`. It logs:

```
TOP: Object
Object
```

Now if I go back to my `Object` class and uncomment `[self addChild:n]` so that the `SKLabelNode` is added as a child to `Object`, this is logged:

```
TOP: SKLabelNode
Object
SKLabelNode
SKSpriteNode
```

Why does adding an `SKLabelNode` as a child to a class derived from `SKSpriteNode` cause the touch to detect the object itself, along with an `SKLabelNode` and an `SKSpriteNode`?

Furthermore, why is the `SKLabelNode` on top? I have its zPosition as -1 so I would assume that in `touchesBegan:withEvent:` of another class, the `Object` would be detected as on top?

Surely, I am not understanding an important concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `nodeAtPoint` to check for the node in `-touchesEnded:`, it will definitely return the topmost node at the point of the touch, which in this case, is the `SKLabelNode`. There are a few ways you can go around this:

**Making the subclass detect it's own touches**

The cleanest way would be to make the Object subclass detect it's own touches. This can be done by setting it's `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`. This can be done in the init method itself.

```
-(instanceType) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, implement the touch delegate methods in the class itself. Since the LabelNode has its `userInteractionEnabled` property set by default as `NO`, the touch delegates will still be triggered when it is tapped.

You can use either delegation, NSNotificationCenter or a direct message to the parent in the touch delegate.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    //Send a message to the delegate, which is the SKScene, should be included in protocol
    [self.delegate handleTouchOnObjectInstance:self];

    //or, send a message directly to the SKScene, the method should be included in the interface.
    MyScene *myScene = (MyScene*)self.scene;
    [myScene handleTouchOnObjectInstance:self];
}
```

**Checking for the node's parent**

In the touch delegate of the SKScene, you can check whether the parent node of the SKLabelNode returned from `nodeAtPoint` is an instance of the C class.

```
//Inside the touch delegate, after extracting touchPoint
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint: touchPoint];

if ([node isKindOfClass: [SKLabelNode class]]) {
    if ([node.parent isKindOfClass: [Object class]])
        [self performOperationOnCInstance: (Object*)node.parent];
} else if ([node isKindOfClass: [Object class]])
    [self performOperationOnCInstance: (Object*)node];
```

**Use nodesAtPoint instead of nodeAtPoint**

This method returns an array of all nodes detected at a certain point. So if the SKLabelNode is tapped, the `nodesAtPoint` method will return the Object node as well.

```
//Inside the touch delegate, after extracting touchPoint
NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint: touchPoint];

for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
    if ( [node isKindOfClass: [Object class]]) {
        [self performOperationOnObjectInstance: (Object*)node];
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

There is a difference between the `zPosition` and the node tree.

The `zPosition` only tells the scene to render nodes in a certain order, whatever their child order may be. This property was introduced to make it easier to specify the order in which a node's children are drawn. If the same were to be achieved by adding the nodes to the parent in a specific order, it becomes difficult to manage the nodes.

When the `nodesAtPoint` method is called, the scene conducts a depth-first search through the node tree to see which nodes intersect the given touch point. This explains the order in which the array is populated.

The `nodeAtPoint` method returns the deepest node according to zPosition which the scene could find.

The following section from Apple's documentation explains it all extensively: [Creating The Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW18)

Comment: I have provided more information and narrowed down the question.

Comment: I have added a further explanation. You already have accepted the answer, which method did you go for?

Comment: Yeah, your answer did end up solving my initial issue. I checked to see if the parent of the detected node was an instance of class Object (class C before I edited my question).